# How can I use a variable within my jsmodbus Javascript function on my HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables, modbus

I am creating a dashboard that I want to display live data from some equipment using modbus. I am using the jsmodbus module and have successfully connected to the equipment and am getting live values. I am doing this through a function from the jsmodbus documentation that is on a scripts.js file. Here is the snippet:

```
socket.on('connect', function () {

  // make some calls

  client.readInputRegisters(509, 6).then(function (resp) {
    
    console.log(resp);

    values_list = resp.response.body._values;
    
    global_values_list.single_value = (values_list[0])
    


    }, console.error);

    
    
    });
  
  socket.connect(options)

const jsmodbus = require('jsmodbus');
```

I simplified the code a bit and changed my variables here but essentially I want to take the 'single_value' variable and use it on a separate html page. I declared the variables at the beginning of the js file to be able to use them globally, and also made sure that the js file was linked to my HTML page. I'm also using setTimeout() on my HTML page to delay the access of the variable until after my js function has run.

I have test variables and another setTimeout() set up on the JS page. The variables are updating as expected on the JS page and logging to the console, but when accessing the same variable from the HTML page, just the variables that are being defined in the function are undefined.

Here is another way of explaining what is happening:

On scripts.js :

- Jsmodbus function is running and populating a list of values (global_values_list)
- setTimeout() function is running after 2000ms that has accurate data for global_values_list as well as test variables
  On HTML page
- setTimeout() function running after 4000 ms that has accurate data for test variables, including variables that I changed within the 2000ms scripts.js setTimeout() function but undefined variables for everything that was defined within jsmodbus

I think this means that my setTimeout() timing is definitely working but there is another issue with how the variable information is stored from the function? I'm really not sure how to address this so any input would be very appreciated. I am also quite new to javascript and HTML so sorry if there are any glaring errors.

Comment: Can you please clarify how you are serving the HTML? Currently I'm not really clear whether you are making the Modbus request every-time the page is requested (and returning HTML that includes the reading) or if you expect changing a variables value on the server will impact the client (probably not be happening - but there are state management libraries that could do this). If you want to update the value multiple times per second I'd suggest using websockets to transmit the updates.

Comment: Right now I believe the Modbus request is just happening every time i run my scripts.js page. I eventually want to change/update the variable periodically but right now I am just running the script and then looking at the variables both within scripts.js and then also on my HTML page console.

Comment: Ok, updating.a variable on the server will have no impact on the code running in the browser. You could include the value returned in the html/js sent to the browser, but it's probably simpler to make a seperate request to get the reading (i.e. js in browser requests `/api/modbus` and the server returns `{"reading": 42}`).